# Indefinite integral of x^x

Tags: integration, proof-explanation, indefinite-integrals

When I searched for a solution to this in the internet, I always read that it can be expressed in closed form, but I haven't found the proof, is there one ? Or we concluded that it is so, just because we can't find one in closed form ?

Comment: [Nope.](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+x%5Ex)

Comment: @TheSimpliFire I know that there is no one in closed form, but it seems that we concluded so just by induction.

Comment: since, for $x>0$, $x^x=e^{x\ln(x)}$, a closed form doesn't seem something to expect...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can write $$x^x=e^{x\log x}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^k(\log x)^k}{k!}$$

Then since the power series converges uniformly,
$$\int x^x\,dx=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\int\frac{x^k(\log x)^k}{k!}\,dx$$

You can then attempt to integrate $\dfrac{x^k(\log x)^k}{k!}$, but there is no closed form: the answer will involve the Gamma function and/or [this integral](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/En-Function.html).